# setTimeout not waiting for the specified interval in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, settimeout

I am trying to change pages based on specific time interval.
I tried using setTimeout, but it run the code immediately regardless the specified time.
Here is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Change Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var oCSS = {
                'font-size' : '18em',
                'height' : '300px',
                'border' : 'thick solid',
                'text-align' : 'center'
            };

            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
            {
                $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "flip";
            });
            $('div[data-role|="page"]').live('pageshow', function(event)
            {
                setTimeout($.mobile.changePage($($(this).attr('NextPage'))), 30000);
            });
        </script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" NextPage='#page2'>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="number">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page2" NextPage='#page3'>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class='number'>3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page3" NextPage='#page4'>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class='number'>2</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page4" NextPage='#page1'>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class='number'>1</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".number").css(oCSS);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You need to use an anonymous function or the JS will be called immediately. In addition, your jQuery seems to be incorrect as well (one too many `$()`). It should be:

```
$('div[data-role|="page"]').live('pageshow', function(event)
{
    // Retrieve attribute of element to be passed to anonymous function
    var functionParam = $(this).attr('NextPage')

    setTimeout(function() {
        // Pass functionParam to function - $(this) will 
        // be out of scope when the function is called
        $.mobile.changePage(functionParam)
    }, 30000);​
});
```

See [`window.setTimeout` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Your reference to `$(this)` will not work (this in the anonymous function ends up being `DOMWindow` <sup>[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/t8gfw/)</sup>) in `setTimeout()`, you need to capture the variable for the function to behave correctly.

```
$('div[data-role|="page"]').live('pageshow', function(event){
  var nextPage = $($(this).attr('NextPage'));
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.changePage(nextPage);
  }, 30000);
});
```

**[Here is a working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/6GDCD/)**